# ROS 2 package Rsrc pipeline fails due to changed tracks.yaml

Tags: ros2, buildfarm

On 3/6/2024 I noticed that the Rsrc Jenkins pipeline for my package failed, even though I haven't changed the package since October.

https://build.ros2.org/job/Rsrc_uJ__catch_ros2__ubuntu_jammy__source/3/console

After investigating, I found the culprit to be a failure to pull down a specific tag from the release repository:

> fatal: Remote branch debian/ros-rolling-catch-ros2_0.2.0-2_jammy not found in upstream origin

I went to look for this tag in the release repo and found some strange commits from an OSRF developer the day before which modified the tracks.yaml file.

https://github.com/ros2-gbp/catch_ros2-release

The specific problem seems to be this change, which increments the release inc from 1 to 2:

https://github.com/ros2-gbp/catch_ros2-release/commit/7110b4e18d52b4cd892588626a78d8f96624cb18

The release increment was 1 when I released the latest version of this package with bloom, and so the `debian/ros-rolling-catch-ros2_0.2.0-2_jammy` tag does not exist. But `debian/ros-rolling-catch-ros2_0.2.0-1_jammy` does, which is the latest version.

I looked at a few other release repositories in ros2-gbp and found that many had similar (if not exactly the same) commits made to them around the same time. For example:

https://github.com/ros2-gbp/ros_foxglove_msgs-release

Does anyone know why these commits were made by OSRF? The pipeline is broken and disabled now because of it.